# How to adjust the input file in Chrome for which it is like IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

When I create an Input using the `JSP` tag below:

```
<html:file property="formFile" styleId="formFile" />
```

I have a different display between chrome and IE :

**Chrome**:

[image]

**IE**:

[image]

how can i change this tag so that i would have the same IE display in Chrome ?

Comment: You've to create a custom input file with css for this. It's just the native rendering of both browser

Comment: see some examples [here](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=input%20file&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything)